# Creating a Windows mountable partition in a file on my phone

Tags: windows, filesystems, android, portable

I have a Galaxy Nexus that only provides MTP and PTP USB connectivity. Because of that, I cannot install [portable applications](http://portableapps.com/) since it does not act as a USB device (here is [word from a Google engineer](http://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/mg14z/whoa_whoa_ics_doesnt_support_usb_mass_storage/c30q93p) as to why this was done).

Is there a way I could create some sort of mountable partition that resides in a file on the Galaxy Nexus and I could then mount that on Windows and install/run portable applications?

I was thinking something similar to how [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) does it's magic. However, I am hoping it doesn't need something installed locally. If it requires me to first run something from the phone and then I could mount the volume, that would be fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, ICS does have USB mass storage support. Try this:

1. Unplug the phone from the computer
2. Open `Settings`
3. Tap `More...` under `Wireless and network`
4. Tap `USB utilities`
5. Tap the `Connect storage to PC` button
6. If it asks you to turn off USB debugging, press `OK`
7. Plug the phone to the computer
8. Tap the `Turn on USB storage` button
9. The phone might now misleadingly ask you to turn **off** USB storage. Tap `OK`

And now you should have a new USB mass storage device on your computer. When done using the device, eject it from the computer and tap the `Turn off USB storage` button

The above steps work on my Samsung Galaxy S2 running ICS 4.0.3. I do not have a Galaxy Nexus to test, but the steps should be the same, or at least very similar

Comment: Galaxy Nexus unfortunately does not have UMS.

Comment: Hmm… Google searching confirms that. I'm not familiar at all with MTP, but since they don't offer block-level access, your request [creating a mountable image on a MTP device] seems pretty much impossible. Truecrypt creates and mounts something similar to a loop device [which Windows doesn't have], but for that it still needs block-level access

Comment: I'm also not familiar at all with portableapps, but I think you could take an empty usb drive, install portableapps on it, then copy everything from the usb drive to your MTP device. Then mount the MTP device normally, and it might just work!

Comment: Tried that and for whatever reason, it does not unfortunately.